# How to set a global variable using MySQLContainer

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers

There is a way to set the global variable: `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=true`, using test docker container?

I have the following code in my unit test:

```
@Container
public static final MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>()
        .withDatabaseName("test")
        .withPassword("123")
        .withUsername("test")
        .withExposedPorts(3306)
        .withInitScript("database-creation-scripts/mysql-install.sql");
```

the container starts, but the default value is false:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timestamp%';
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | OFF   |
| log_timestamps                  | UTC   |
+---------------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I could not find a method `.with[...]` that set global variables in the MySQLContainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can pass configuration parameters to your MySQL docker container with command-line flags like:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:5.7 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

You can mirror this with Testcontainers using `.withCommand():

```
@Container
public static final MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>()
        .withDatabaseName("test")
        .withPassword("123")
        .withUsername("test")
        .withExposedPorts(3306)
        .withInitScript("database-creation-scripts/mysql-install.sql")
        .withCommand("--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp");
```